# How can I solve this PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

I got the following equation from physics.

$$C \sin \theta \frac{\partial T}{\partial \theta} = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}        \right)$$
where boundary conditions are

$T=T_w$ for $r<r_0$,

$T=T_0$ where $r \rightarrow\infty$,

and $C, T_0, T_w, r_0$ are constant.

(Symmetrical for all $\theta$)

I would like to find $\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}$ where $r=r_0$ from the equation.

How can I solve using Mathematica? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It will help in the future to show what you have tried.

There does not seem to be a solution due to the BC you given. May be this will get you started to see why that is.

\begin{align*}
C\sin\theta\frac{\partial T}{\partial\theta}  & =\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial
}{\partial r}\left(  r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)  \\
& =\frac{1}{r}\left(  r\frac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{\partial
T}{\partial r}\right)  \\
& =\frac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial
r}
\end{align*}

Using sepration of variables, let $T=R\left(  r\right)  \Theta\left(
\theta\right)  $. Substituting this into the above gives

\begin{align*}
C\sin\theta\Theta^{\prime}R  & =R^{\prime\prime}\Theta+\frac{1}{r}R^{\prime
}\Theta\\
C\sin\theta\frac{\Theta^{\prime}}{\Theta}  & =\frac{R^{\prime\prime}}{R}
+\frac{1}{r}\frac{R^{\prime}}{R}
\end{align*}

Since LHS depends only on $\theta$ and RHS depends only on $r$ and they are
the same, then they must must both equal to some constant. Say $-\lambda$.
Hence we have two ODE's to solve

\begin{align*}
\frac{R^{\prime\prime}}{R}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{R^{\prime}}{R}  & =-\lambda\\
C\sin\theta\frac{\Theta^{\prime}}{\Theta}  & =-\lambda
\end{align*}

or

\begin{align*}
R^{\prime\prime}+\frac{1}{r}R^{\prime}+\lambda R  & =0\\
C\sin\theta\Theta^{\prime}+\lambda\Theta & =0
\end{align*}

Starting with the $R$ ode, and transfering the boundary conditions gives

\begin{align*}
R^{\prime\prime}+\frac{1}{r}R^{\prime}+\lambda R  & =0\\
R\left(  \infty\right)    & =T_{0}\\
R\left(  r\right)    & =T_{\omega}\qquad r<r_{0}
\end{align*}

There are 3 cases to consider. $\lambda=0,\lambda<0,\lambda>0$. The solution
to the ODE without BC is in terms of Bessel functions.

case  $\lambda=0$ does not satisfy the second BC. It has solution
$R\left(  r\right)  =T_{0}$.

case $\lambda<0$ and $\lambda>0$ Mathematica does not give a solution.

You might want to double check your BC on $R\left(  r\right)  $.

Code

```
ClearAll[R, r, lambda, T0]
ode = R''[r] + 1/r R'[r] + lambda R[r] == 0
bc = R[Infinity] == T0;
sol = DSolve[ode, R[r], r]
sol = DSolve[{ode, bc}, R[r], r, Assumptions -> lambda < 0]
sol = DSolve[{ode, bc}, R[r], r, Assumptions -> lambda > 0]
```

Version 12.3